# Is there any way to sort a python list by length (longest string first?)

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-3.6

I need to sort my list comprised of variables created through a class by their name (ex. `var.name`).

I have tried the `.sort(key=len, reverse=True)` method but it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/TPF-Tests/main.py", line 92, in <module>
    newvar=shop(1,possibleplace, 70, inventory)
  File "/home/runner/TPF-Tests/main.py", line 64, in shop
    itemlist.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
TypeError: object of type 'item' has no len()
```

I am a beginner so explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least one element of the list is not a valid argument to `len`.

Comment: maybe try `itemlist.sort(key=lambda x: len(str(x)), reverse=True)`

Comment: The problem is in `itemlist`. I suspect that one or more (if not all) of its elements are of type `item`, instead of type `str`.

Comment: All of the elements are the class item. I'm trying to sort them by the name.
class item:
  def __init__(self, name, plural, description, type, stats):
    self.name = name
    self.plural = plural
    self.type = type
    self.stats = stats

Comment: `item` doesn't define `__len__`, so you haven't define what the length of an `item` instance *is*.

Comment: @JonSG That fixed it tysm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort key (`key=len`) doesn't make any sense. You need to sort on the length of the `item.name` attribute:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.name), reverse=True)
```

For example:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class item:
    name: str


mylist = [
    item(name='bob'),
    item(name='alice'),
    item(name='mallory'),
    item(name='mallory'),
    item(name='david'),
    item(name='chuck'),
        ]


mylist.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.name))
print(mylist)
```